# Integrate AdobeCreativeSDKCore in iOS Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, adobecreativesdk

All

I am trying to integrate the Private Framework AdobeCreativeSDKCore into my Xcode project/

I followed the steps from the adobe provided documentation for the integration.
https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html

I got the following error after completed steps.

```
bash: “/Users/KiranKumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoEditing-gkklxzrvccqayvfgazofrcjdcidl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoEditing.app/Frameworks/AdobeCreativeSDKCore.framework/strip-frameworks.sh”: No such file or directory
```

Is any one integrated this framework please let me know, how to integrate.  Your feedback will be appreciated

Comment: did this issue resolved?